# Merge data from XML to SQL dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, merge

I have problem. I need to get XML with data into SQL database. I know how to do that for one table but I need doing this generically for multiple tables. So there is multiple variants of number of columns, data types, names...

I am trying it in MS SQL procedure. I tried to get data from XML to temp table. For one table is it ok but it is not generic. After that I will use typical MERGE statement but I dont know if it is generic.

Comment: I am using this example for one xml file: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f82e9a/merge-statement-using-xml-data-in-sql-server534/ But what can I do if I need it for more different xml files and more tables?

Comment: Without knowing your XML it is almost impossible even to guess what you might need. Please try to provide a (reduced!) sample of your XML and tell us more about the structure of the target tables and their relations. Best was a [mcve] with DDL, sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [XML Bulk Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-xpath-queries/bulk-load-xml/introduction-to-xml-bulk-load-sqlxml-4-0), although you will still need to provide the mapping between XML attributes and SQL tables and columns - in this case, in the form of XML schemas.